# Counting number of a certain type of value in a MySQL table row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I know how to count number of values in a row, using something such as:

```
$num = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(rowName) FROM tableName");
```

but I have a table that contains rows that have columns that organize the type the row is. Such as a column in one of the rows is: 'otherType' which can vary in between three different values. How can I count each different value?

Basically, I want to be able to count 'otherType->Character', 'otherType->Entity', 'otherType->Item'.

Is this possible?

Sorry..I'm not so good at explaining.

---

EDIT:

So, my table looks like this:

```
id | forGame | otherType | otherDesc
1  | ...     | Entity    | ...
2  | ...     | Item      | ...
3  | ...     | Character | ...
```

I want to be able to count how many of 'Entity', how many of 'Item', how many of 'Character'..is there a way to do that?

It would be preferable to be able to have variables such as:

```
$numEntities = [query]
$numItems = [query]
$numCharacters = [query]
```

or otherwise how might I get the count of just one at a time?

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(otherType),otherType FROM mainSite_others group by otherType")
```

works fine, but how do I get each value by itself? an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(otherType),otherType FROM tableName group by otherType;
```

hope it helps

Comment: I didn't know that you could do that, thanks! I'll give it a go as a query and see what it returns. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sorry, this won't work as I think that sorts it by the type as in VARCHAR, etc.. I edited my question, any ideas?

Comment: one type can be also another type?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confusing you, that query worked -- I added more to my question, any ideas there? There is only one 'otherType' per item in DB.

Comment: Okay, nevermind. Thank you for all of your help! I'm going to use that query and fetch an array with PHP. You rule man! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: hehe, I went out for some food. I still don't know if I helped